# How to run javascript in flutter_inappwebview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I found it difficult when I want to run javascript in package `flutter_inappwebview`, Previously I tried with `webview_flutter` I was able to run `runJavascript` but there was a problem when I used webview_flutter I could not upload this file for example when I used `webview_flutter`

```
final json =
              jsonEncode(TawkVisitor(name: "jhon", email: "jhon@mail.com"));

          String javascriptString;

          javascriptString =
              '''Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {};Tawk_API.onLoad = function() {Tawk_API.setAttributes($json);''';

          await controller.runJavascript(javascriptString);

          setState(() {});
```

can you guys help how to run javascript in packages `flutter_inappwebview`

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/javascript/injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
String yourCode = "alert('JS Running')";
controller.evaluateJavascript(source: yourCode).then((result) {
debugPrint(result);
});
```

Comment: I agree logically it is the same